# Bluetooth import for Python Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, bluetooth, pi-3

I have successfully connected my cell phone to the Raspberry Pi's onboard bluetooth. I know the Bluetooth works, but I cannot get `import bluetooth` to work properly.

I get this error when I run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/filename.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bluetooth 
ImportError: No module named 'Bluetooth'
```

How do I fix this, or what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Did you install PyBlueZ?

Comment: Says unable to locate package PyBlueZ

Answer (score 9):

You need to install bluetooth library

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez libbluetooth-dev
sudo python3 -m pip install pybluez
```

and try again your code.

Regards

Edit: Answer's source was broken, so deleted

Comment: Those packages are already installed, each says: package is already the newest version....    The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required: py py-upstream-doc

Comment: did you run `pip install bluez` ?

Comment: "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement bluez" ... Cleaning up... "No distributions at all found for bluez", "Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Is your python version over 3.5 ?

Comment: maybe thats the problem... python -V returned Python 2.7.9. how do I use or get 3.5?

Comment: Just noticed, I was using the Python 3.4.2 Shell under menu > programming

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install bluez`

Comment: That didn't work... I followed [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=134828) tutorial to upgrade to Python 3.5 and ran my code again but it still did not work, I received the same error