# Python import bluetooth module

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to send and recieve data over bluetoth on my Raspberry Pi 4, via a bluetooth terminal app on my phone. I've found a couple of tutorials (e.g. [this](https://technologisttips.com/raspberry-pi-bluetooth/) and [this](https://www.technologyrecipes.com/using-blueterm-app-to-communicate-over-ble-between-an-android-device-and-raspberry-pi/)) which use python scripts involving `import bluetooth`, but when I try and run them I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bluetooth'
```

It is in fact the exact same problem as in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45246/bluetooth-import-for-python-raspberry-pi-3), but the answer and comments given there haven't helped at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth import for Python Raspberry Pi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45246/bluetooth-import-for-python-raspberry-pi-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pybluez module [isn't under active development](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez#contributors-wanted) according to the repository. It also doesn't use the preferred D-Bus API.

Another alternative is the BlueDot library which has a good [Bluetooth Server](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothserver) included in it. There is a blog introducing it:

https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2017/07/python-bluetooth-rfcomm-client-server.html

Comment: That's useful to know, thank you; the answer above fixed my problem in the short term so I have accepted it, but I will look into BlueDot for a more long term solution.

Comment: do you know of any other resources for using the BlueDot raspberry pi server with an android bluetooth terminal that isn't the bluedot app? I like the simplicity of the library but can't get the raspberry pi server to connect to anything other than the BlueDot app itself

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114280/121848 and https://github.com/martinohanlon/BlueDot/issues/160#issuecomment-751395374

Comment: Thank you, pulseaudio -k as suggested in the github link fixed the problem. Kind of annoying to have to do that every time but at least it's working. Have now accepted this as an answer to my question, thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked. If you don't need pulseAudio then I'm sure you can remove it (`apt remove pulseaudio`) or stop it it starting on boot (`autospawn = no` in `/etc/pulse/client.conf`)

Answer (score 4):

On raspbian Buster you need to install:

1. `python3-bluez` for python3.*
2. `python-bluez` for python2.7

---

To install it:

```
sudo apt install python3-bluez
```

or (for python2):

```
sudo apt install python-bluez
```

Comment: Thank you, it was python3-bluez I was missing it turns out (already had bluez and python-bluez installed)